# how to dynamic function use ajax jquery in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

so I use this code to make everything that has the $(".select2") element will process ajax according to the rest of the data sent via html

```
$(".select2").each(function () {
        let element = $(this);

        element.select2({
            theme: "bootstrap",
            placeholder: element.data("placeholder"),
            ajax: {
                url: element.data("url"),
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 100,
                cache: true,
                data: function (params) { return { q: params.term } },
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results:  $.map(data.results, function (item) {
                            return {
                                text:  item.bank_name, /***** this *******/
                                id: item.id /***** this *******/
                            }
                        })
                    };
                }
            },
        });
    })
```

I've added element.data ("placeholder") and element.data ("url") in jquery, while how to send it with this html code

```
<select id="bank_id" name="bank_id" 
     class="fetch_bank form-control select2"
     data-placeholder="Choose Bank" 
     data-url="/api/bank/fetch">
</select>
```

sending it ajax will return the following results

```
{
    code: 200
    error: false
    message: "loaded!"
    results: [
        {id: 1, bank_name: "AMERICAN EXPRESS BANK LTD"}, 
        {id: 2, bank_name: "ANGLOMAS INTERNASIONAL BANK"},
        ....
    ]
}
```

I have 3 records that return json, to display to select2, the column is as below

```
Bank(id, bank_name)
School(id, school_name)
Status(id, status)
```

but the problem is, how do i make 'processResults' dynamic? which I have marked with a comment / ***** this ******* /

While the 3 data has different keys, how do I make the select2 function dynamic?

thanks, I hope someone answers my question :)

Comment: Define in more specific terms what you mean by *"make it dynamic"*. What do you need it to do differently than what you have shown? Does the current approach not  work?

Comment: There's an issue in your code that's likely not related or copy-paste error:  `callback(data.results);` is *inside* the `.map` but *after* the `return` - so it does nothing.

Comment: Try `$.map(data.results, function(item) { ... }).get()` as `results:` is expecting an array, not a jquery-array

Comment: sorry, actually there is no ```callback(data.results)```, it's just testing

Comment: I have 3 select2 with different data, so instead of making 3 select2 () of course the code will be longer, it's better to make it dynamic, 1 function that can be used multiple times

Comment: Of the 3 select2 (), have different results, such as bank (id, bank_name), school (id, school_name), status (id, status_name)